# add space between two html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add some space between my timestamp and id here is my code that i code. How can i do that?

css:

```
.body {
  flex: 0.8;
  padding: 30px;
}
.Upbox {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.box {
  display: inline-flex;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
}
```

html + javascript:

```
<div className="body">
  {forum.map((item) => (
    <div className="Upbox">
      <h2>{item.post_content}</h2>
      <div className="box">
        <h5>{item.post_date}</h5>
        <h5>{item.user_id}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

it looks like that i want to add space between
Sun, 06 Dec 2020 15:20:54 GMT 1:
[image: Current looks]

Comment: do you want to add the space between these `<h5>`  with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal whitespace might solve your problem, but it's better if you use padding in your CSS.

```
h5 {
   padding-right: 4px;
}
```